# Django form not saving data

Tags: django-3.1

This is a normal form filling code where I created form and passing request.post into it. The post request data is captured properly but is not getting saved after been passed into forms. The django version 3.1 is the base lang.

```
===view===
def adst(request):
    lists   = Site.objects.filter(deleted=False)
    country = Country.objects.filter(deleted=False)
    company = Company.objects.filter(deleted=False)
    region  = Region.objects.filter(deleted=False)
    location= Location.objects.filter(deleted=False)
    sbu     = SBU.objects.filter(deleted=False)
    delta   = {'status': True}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)                                     # Print_Output
        request.POST                = request.POST.copy()
        request.POST['inserted_by'] = request.user.id
        form = SiteForm(request.POST)
        **if form.is_valid():**
            form.save()
    print(request.GET)                                          # Print_Output
    context = {'form' : SiteForm(), 'list' : lists, 
    'data' : delta, 'sbu' : sbu,'country' : country,
    'company' : company, 'region' : region,
    'location' : location}
    return render(request, 'masters/site.html', context)

===Post Data===
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['sdtbHHn5OVAf19kkaJUlijHzURZEHNNLKm7PLnR6bxrodIKH4rbgB'], 'country': ['India'], 'company': ['GILI'], 'region': ['north'], 'location': ['Vikhroli'], 'sbu': ['goejo nw'], 'site': ['asdasd'], 'status': ['on']}>

===Form===
class SiteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ['id','code','site', 'country', 'company', 'region', 'location', 'sbu', 'status','deleted', 'inserted_by', 'updated_by']

===Model===
class Site(models.Model):
    code        = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True, db_column='code')
    site        = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, db_column='site')
    country     = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company     = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region      = models.ForeignKey(Region, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location    = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sbu         = models.ForeignKey(SBU, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status      = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_column='status')
    deleted     = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True, db_column='deleted')
    inserted_by = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, db_column='inserted_by')
    inserted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_column='inserted_on')
    updated_by  = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, db_column='updated_by')
    updated_on  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_column='updated_on')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.site
    
    def datamodify(self):
        return self.inserted_on >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        return self.updated_on >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```